# How to programmatically edit JSON-LD in 'script' elements?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, json-ld

I have several HTML files on my server that contain JSON-LD `script` elements.  I'm looking for an easy way to update specific elements without physically going into each file, changing the code, and re-saving it.

Specifically, I would like to programmatically loop through each file, find the `datePosted` property and update its value to the current date, then save the file on my server.

I'm mostly comfortable using PHP and I've done something like this with HTML files, but never tried updating JSON-LD before.

Wondering if anyone knows how to do this with JavaScript or PHP.  If not could someone point me in the right direction of a good parser that works with JSON-LD?

Sample JSON-LD:

```json
 {
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "JobPosting",
   "datePosted": "2018-01-23"
 }
```

Comment: Better way to use database

Comment: try `awk` or `perl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was pretty easy, just needed to use json_decode and json_encode to make it work:

```
$file = "file-path-to-json-ld";
$string = file_get_contents($file); // pulls the file
$json = json_decode($string, true); //creates a searchable array

var_dump($json); // just to see what elements and values are in the decoded array

$json['element-name-in-json-ld'] = "new-value-for-element";  //change any value you like

$updatedString = json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);  //re-encode backing into json

file_put_contents($file, $updatedString);  // put file back
```